# Implicit lifting when combining / mixing mtl-style typeclass constraints

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I'm currently refactoring some Haskell code that I have that interacts with `Data.Time`. Ultimately I have a bunch of functions that interact with time:

```
getCurrentTime :: IO UTCTime
getCurrentTime = T.getCurrentTime

getCurrentDay :: IO Day
getCurrentDay = T.utctDay <$> getCurrentTime

daysUntil :: Day -> IO Integer
daysUntil day = T.diffDays day <$> getCurrentDay
```

etc etc and so on, ultimately these are just my own helper functions that are all based around `T.getCurrentTime` from `Data.Time`. Which is the 'effect' of all of these functions.

The first refactor I did to this code was to simply change them to use `MonadIO` to allow them to be used in the various transformer stacks compatible with this typeclass:

```
getCurrentTime :: MonadIO m => m UTCTime
getCurrentTime = liftIO T.getCurrentTime

getCurrentDay :: MonadIO m => m Day
getCurrentDay = T.utctDay <$> getCurrentTime

daysUntil :: MonadIO m => Day -> m Integer
daysUntil day = T.diffDays day <$> getCurrentDay
```

This is straightforward enough as I just need to lift `T.getCurrentTime` and the rest of the implementations just follow suit.

Recently though I have been reading about stubbing and faking effects in Haskell, and would like to be able to run these functions with a fake `UTCTime` result for `getCurrentTime`.

Going off some of the things I have read online, and looking at how Pandoc implements separating out pure and effectful operations, I've come up with this:

```
newtype TimePure a = TimePure
  { unTimePure :: Reader UTCTime a
  } deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadReader UTCTime)

newtype TimeEff m a = TimeEff
  { unTimeIO :: m a
  } deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO)

class (Functor m, Applicative m, Monad m) => TimeMonad m where
  getCurrentTime :: m UTCTime

instance TimeMonad TimePure where
  getCurrentTime = ask

instance MonadIO m => TimeMonad (TimeEff m) where
  getCurrentTime = liftIO T.getCurrentTime

getCurrentDay :: TimeMonad m => m Day
getCurrentDay = T.utctDay <$> getCurrentTime

daysUntil :: TimeMonad m => Day -> m Integer
daysUntil day = T.diffDays day <$> getCurrentDay
```

Again, other than the additional definitions at the top, I haven't had to change much - my original functions just need to change to use `TimeMonad m` rather than `MonadIO m`.

This is ideal, and I am able to run my time functions in a pure context now.

However now when I come to some real world code, given an example function like this that interacts with the DB:

```
markArticleRead :: MonadIO m => Key Article -> SqlPersistT m ()
markArticleRead articleKey =
  updateLastModified articleKey =<< getCurrentTime
```

I have to adjust my function like so:

```
markArticleRead :: (MonadIO m, TimeMonad m) => Key Article -> SqlPersistT m ()
markArticleRead articleKey =
  updateLastModified articleKey =<< lift getCurrentTime
```

Obviously I have to do this as `getCurrentTime` does not need `MonadIO` to run. The issue I have is with the re-introduction of lift, this is needed because there is two 'layers' of the transformer stack, rather than one (I think thats an appropriate explaination?).

One of the nice things about the introduction of `MonadIO` was it removed the need for having to lift things everywhere, and it made functions like this, which a lot of the time contain business logic etc, a lot less noisy. Is there a way for me to re-gain this benefit, where I can get mtl style implicit lifting, or is it impossible now due to the types I have introduced?

Comment: I don't know exactly what your use cases are, but I think it makes more sense to put your business logic in simple pure functions that take the current time as an argument, or in a `State` monad. The way you have it here seems a little overengineered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is `TimeEff`, its just not needed. The interface separation is type classes, not concrete Monads. `TimePure` is good because you need some Monad to provide facilities for testing, but since any old `MonadIO` can do the trick for the IO case, you just don't need to specific a concrete Monad for that.

`TimeEff` as you have it adds only one thing to your program, and it's the need to use `lift` to convert a `TimeEff m` to `m`. And since this works forall `MonadIO` we can use `UndecidableInstances` to permit unification without even adding `TimeMonad` to the effectful case. (I know `UndecidableInstances` sounds bad, but it's not)

### [Running example](https://repl.it/join/plrfncsm-isaacshapira)

```
instance (Monad m, MonadIO m) => TimeMonad m where
  getCurrentTime = liftIO T.getCurrentTime

markArticleRead :: MonadIO m => Key Article -> SqlPersistT m ()
markArticleRead articleKey =
  updateLastModified articleKey =<< getCurrentTime
```

---

Some other notes.

```hs
class (Functor m, Applicative m, Monad m) => TimeMonad m where
```

can be

```hs
class Monad m => TimeMonad m where
```

since `Monad` already has `Applicative` and `Functor` as superclasses. So those come along for free. Now as a matter of personal taste, I would even leave out `Monad`

```hs
class GetsTime m where
  getCurrentTime :: m UTCTime
```

This kind of decoupling is nice, both because it makes your code more general, but also because it removes any relationship to algebras. The class here really has no laws, and is just not algebraic, so it's nice to leave those relationships open imho. This would mean you need to add annotations in some places, but I feel it's a good thing to document the algebraic constraint and effectful constrain separately.

```hs
getCurrentDay :: (Functor m, TimeMonad m) => m Day
getCurrentDay = T.utctDay <$> getCurrentTime
```

Comment: I suspect there is at least one law, which relies on an `Applicative` constraint: `liftA2 (<=) getCurrentTime (m *> getCurrentTime) = liftA2 (\_ _ -> True) getCurrentTime (m *> getCurrentTime)`. I suspect you'd also want to say that `getCurrentTime` doesn't change the world: something like `() <$ getCurrentTime = pure ()`.

Answer (score 2):

For mtl-style effects, it's usual to define lifting instances for the common monad transformers.  Such as `TimeMonad m => TimeMonad (ReaderT r m)`.  That lets you leave out the `lift` in `markArticleRead`.

Another option is to skip the monad transformer `TimeEff`.  It doesn't carry any additional information, and you don't mention needing to prevent time functions from being called in other `MonadIO` types.  If you write the instance `MonadIO m => TimeMonad m`, then `markArticleRead` doesn't need the `TimeMonad` constraint or `lift`.  This instance overlaps the one in the first paragraph; pick one.

If you do want a monad transformer, you might prefer to merge your `TimePure` and `TimeEff`.  `newtype TimeT m a = TimeT (ReaderT UTCTime m a)` would allow you to inject a chosen `UTCTime` into effect stacks that do not include `IO` (or the constraints of which do not ensure IO).  Then you can define `TimePure` in terms of `TimeT`, as `transformers` defines `Reader` and the rest.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, would you mind adding a code example of what you mean to it? I tried to refactor using a `newtype` `TimeT` as you suggested but I still run into the issue where I need to go back to explicit `lift`ing when mixing DB effects and IO/time effects... There is a good chance I haven't implemented it in the way you were trying to convey

Comment: I'll add code when I have a bit more time.  Briefly: `markArticleRead` doesn't use the transformer at all.  If you are following the suggestion in my third paragraph you will also want the instance in the first paragraph.